# Wave-function (in real space) of electron in Graphene nano-ribbons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hamiltonian, graphene, tight-binding

I was trying to solve the tight binding model of Graphene nano-strip in the zig-zag configuration. It looks something like this:

[image]

It has a very beautiful band structure. In order to calculate the band structure, I wrote the Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
     H_0 = \sum_{i}\sum_{m=1,3,\cdots} t\big[a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i,m} + a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i-1,m} + a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i,m-1}+h.c.\big]\\
         +\sum_{i}\sum_{m=2,4,\cdots} t\big[a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i,m} + a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i+1,m} + a^{\dagger}_{i,m}b_{i,m-1}+h.c.\big]
\end{split}    
\end{align}
Using Fourier transform (in y direction where the strip is infinite), I found out the Hamiltonian in k-space, which turns out to be a very large ($(2N+2) \times (2N+2$)) matrix. After finding the eigenvalues (numerically of course), I have the band structure. However, I also want to find how the wave-function of looks in the real space (as function of x or as a function of lattice sites). I couldn't figure out this. Can someone tell me the steps/algorithm to how to calculate wave-function numerically?

Comment: Have you found the eigenvectors of your large matrix? They are (after appropriate array reshaping) the wavefunctions in $k$-space.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes i thought that, I found the wave-functions in k-space which are big column matrices. But then I got confused that, if I do inverse Fourier transform, I should in theory get real space wavefunction but it will remain in column matrices. So what  is the meaning of that?

Comment: That's why I'm talking about array reshaping. Remember that each entry of your column vector corresponds to a particular value of $\vec k$. So basically, you have a 2D lattice of values, flattened into a column.